# Google translate api response not in target language

Tags: node.js, translation, google-translate, google-api-nodejs-client, google-translation-api

So I was using google translate api `npm @google-cloud/translate` with the following input:

```
translate.translate('Vijayashankara', {from: 'en', to: 'hi'})
```

Wanted to translate 'Vijayashankara' to 'Hindi'. I get the following response:

```
["Vijayashankara",{"data":{"translations":[{"translatedText":"Vijayashankara"}]}}]
```

Is there any way for me to get the response as `विजयशंकर`, which is the hindi transliteration of 'Vijayashankara' ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, name is 2 words.

After adding a space between words (that is, space before Capital letters), it works correctly:

`Vijaya shankara` converts to `विजया शंकरा`

https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=hi&text=Vijaya%20shankara

`Vijaya shankar` converts to `विजया शंकर`

https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=hi&text=Vijaya%20shankar

---

**More details:**

As names can be written without a space, may be, google should assume the space.

It does give `Did you mean:` for both success & unsuccessful translation.

If unsuccessful, the source and target text will be same.
then we could use `Did you mean:`
however sometimes it is wrong:

`VijayShankara`  gives the `Did you mean` as `Vijay Shankar`, but should be `Vijay Shankara`
`VijayaShankara` gives the `Did you mean` as `Vijay Shankar`, but should be `Vijaya Shankara`

Hope that helps.

Comment: AFAIK "Did you mean" is not part of API response. It's present only on the browser.

Comment: @myusuf  It looks like it is part of the API response, see `console.log(res.from.text.didYouMean);` on this page https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate-api. This repo does not work anymore, but the newer clone works, see https://github.com/vitalets/google-translate-api (We just have to import the .js files and use package.json dependencies, it works, verified yesterday). On the other hand, in the above response, I was only emphasizing on space to be added to get correct results.

Answer (score 0):

I tried translating 'Arpit' to Hindi using the same line that you used:

```
translate.translate('Arpit', 'hi')
```

and had the same response as you.

What I did to get 'अर्पित' was to [specify the source language](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/issues/484#issuecomment-330734593):

```
const options = {
  from: "en",
  to: "hi"
}

translate.translate("Arpit", options);
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out too. You beat me to the accepted answer :)

Comment: So this solution worked for 'Arpit', but not for 'Vijayashankara'. So I am still looking for the right answer. Any help would be great :)

Comment: In this case doing the inverse process (writing `विजयशंकर` and translating to English) will output `Vijayashankar` and not `Vijayashankara` as you wrote. And if you reproduce the sound of `विजयशंकर`, the final 'a' is not spelt (at least to me, but I don't speak Hindi).
So maybe is just a typo, but if you are sure that the translation is `Vijayashankara` and not `Vijayashankar`, you can suggest an edit [here](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=hi&text=Vijayashankar)

Comment: When Hindi names are transliterated into English, often an extra 'A' is suffixed at the end. In the above word, there are two names, 'Vijay' and 'Shankar'. Both names have been spelt with the suffix 'A' and then merged together to form one name. Both spellings would be considered correct (with A and without A), and I expected google's ML model to understand and incorporate this nuance. I have suggested this edit. Thanks for your help :)